# Getting a hash of hash of habtm through strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The parameters that my form sends to the controller contain this :

```
"biblio"=>{"authors_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>""}}, "title"=>"", "subtitle"=>"",
```

How do I get the author_attributes through the strong parameters?

I tried:

```
params.require(:biblio).permit(
                        :title, 
                        :subtitle,
                        authors_attributes:["0"][:nom] )
```

Or better: how do I get rid of that "0" in authors_attributes, that rails automagically inserted?

Comment: there's a nice guide here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#nested-parameters

Comment: That's a very nice guide that I read numberous times and in the end not even reading what I was reading...